# Extract object's content from pdf circuit scematic file

Tags: pdf

I would like to extract content (electronic component's properties) from a pdf schematic file : see image below. If I could have access to the person who designed the circuit, there is no question obviously

[image]

Thanks in advance

Tuan

Comment: In which programming language do you plan to implement that task? Which pdf library are you going to use? Van you share the pdf in question?

Comment: I'd like to have a quick and dirty way to do it because it's a one time job. However, if it's not too obscure the code, in popular language like Java or Python or even R, I am open to proposition too.

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question?

Comment: I am sorry that would not be possible because it is a document of my client...

Comment: Without a sample PDF I cannot determine how those information are stored. Sorry.

Comment: I expected that too. However, I discover that the pdf file is exported using sch2pdf package, which is a module of mentor design suite. I think without the original software that created the psf file, there is no easy way to do what I want.